# Element not found in dropdown menu

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image]I have tried all selectors even action builder. But nothing seems to be working.

I am trying to run it on chrome

I get No Such Element Exception

- Load Baubleabar
- Add any item
- Click on Shopping cart
- Click on View Shopping Bag ( from Drop down)

Thanks...

Here is the HTML

```
 <li class="_JS_UserLoggedOut header_subNav_listItem" style="display:inline-    block">
    <li class="cartDropdown_container _JS_cartWidget header_subNav_listItem">
    <a class="header_subNav_link header_subNav_cartIcon" href="/checkout/cart/">
    <span class="cart-qty-indicator _JS_cartQty">1</span>
    <div class="cartDropdown __showCartWidget">
    <button class="dropdown-cart-scrollup btn_reset _JS_crt_up" style="display: none;">
    <ul class="_JS_scrollUI cart-item-container _JS_cartItemsContainer" data-item-count="" data-scrollable="false">
    <div class="cartDropdown_emptyMsg">
    <button class="dropdown-cart-scrolldown btn_reset _JS_crt_down" style="display: none;">
   <div class="cartDropdown_subtotal group">
   <a class="btn_highlight cartDropdown_viewCartLink" href="/checkout/cart/">
   </div>
   </li>
```

Comment: Please add the html source code for more clarity on the question

Answer (score 0):

Please, can you show us the html code that you want to select and your webdriver code? Without these it is hard to know the problem's reason.

Using Selenium in C#, there is a method that can help you: it will match the value, name or id of the option

```
public void SelectIn(By by, string value)
{
    var dropDownListBox = Driver.FindElement(by);
    var clickThis = new SelectElement(dropDownListBox);

    clickThis.Options.First(o =>
        o.Text.ToLower() == value.ToLower() 
        || o.GetAttribute("value").ToLower() == value.ToLower()
        || o.GetAttribute("id").ToLower() == value.ToLower())
    .Click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below code:

```
Thread.sleep(2000);//don't use this, use explicit wait.

 //click on shopping bag at top
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".header_subNav_link.header_subNav_cartIcon")).click();
 Thread.sleep(2000);

//if u want to get total number of items from here, use it
List<WebElement> elem = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#cart-items>li.cart-item"));
System.out.println("total product in ur bag is "+elem.size());

  // click on view shopping bag. 
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".shopping-cart-icon-small")).click();
  Thread.sleep(2000);

//get total number of product from here
List<WebElement> elems = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("article.cart_checkoutReview_item"));
System.out.println("total product in ur bag is "+elems.size());
```

let me know what happens.
U can use javascript for click

```
  WebElement element =     driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".header_subNav_link.header_subNav_cartIcon"));
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for responding. But 

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".shopping-cart-icon-small")).click(); 

does not work. Even

 List<WebElement> elem = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#cart-items>li.cart-item"));
System.out.println("total product in ur bag is "+elem.size());

 gives me 0 quantity. It should give me 1. I have tried class name, xpath but view shopping bag does not get clicked.

Comment: it works fine in my machine.....my code portion is only to get after adding product to bag. That means u have to fist add some product in ur bag throug code...before my code ....than my code will works

Comment: I have that code.  I have all the code working but clicking View shopping Bag on cart drop down. The Pink button View Shopping Bag(1 Items)

Comment: Before any click use wait....and for click use javascript as i given in my code.if cant click let me know what error it shows

Comment: I tried that. It didn't work . I spoke to the developer. Even if cart icon has
  
     <a class="header_subNav_link header_subNav_cartIcon" href="/checkout/cart/">  it will only work when you have Java Script is disabled in some browser. One need to click on View Shopping Bag to go to check out page.